# CKEditor. Свой плагин - вставка своего тега

Tags: плагин, ckeditor

CKEditor 4.5.5

Сделал свою кнопку, написал простой плагин. Выделяем текст и выделенный текст заменяем своим. Нужно выделенный текст обвернуть в свой тег или в `span` с неким пользовательским атрибутом

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('skipWord',{
    init: function(editor){
        var cmd = editor.addCommand('skipWord', {
            exec:function(editor){
                editor.insertHtml('<hello>'+editor.getSelection().getSelectedText()+'</hello>' );
            }
        });
        cmd.modes = { wysiwyg : 1, source: 1 };
        editor.ui.addButton('skipWord',{
            label: 'Замена',
            command: 'skipWord',
        });
    },
    icons:'skipWord',
});
```

Плагин почти работает. Если вместо `<hello>` и `</hello>` любой текст не тег - замена происходит нормально, но если слова в виде тэгов, как в примере - ничего не происходит. Что посоветуете?

```
editor.insertHtml('<span skip-word style="color:darkred">'+editor.getSelection().getSelectedText()+'</span>' );
```

Заменяет/добавляет в данном случае нормально, но ни мой идентификатор, ни класс, ни атрибут не отображается, удаляется при вставке. Нужно в дальнейшем парсить текст и находить по каким-то критериям замененные мной слова

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $ckeditor = CKEDITOR.replace($textarea.attr('id'),{
        customConfig: '/js/libs/ckeditor/custom_config.js',
        extraAllowedContent:    'p(left,right,center,gallery)[myAttr];' +
                                'img[!src,alt,title,width,height];' +
                                'iframe[*]'
        ,
        width: '100%',
        height: 400,
        startupMode: 'wysiwyg'});
```

Мне кажется, что нужно добавить разрешение на использование тега и его атрибутов "extraAllowedContent"

Comment: Спасибо! В конфиге просто прописал config.allowedContent = true; и атрибут добавляется без проблем